# WebView.GoBack() not working at first time

Tags: paypal, webview, uwp

I'm trying to throw Webview.GoBack() method in a UWP application.

The WebView is presenting PayPal page and I want to return to another page.

When I throw WebView.GoBack() only works at second time. Why??

My code is:

```
if (webView.CanGoBack)
{
    webView.GoBack();
}
```

No exception is thrown..

Comment: Could you provide more details? A [mcve] would be better. The code you've posted is right. I think the problem may be related to the PayPal page. Have you tried with some other websites? Do they have the same problem?

Comment: I have the same issue in my UWP app. My app has an embedded browser  which shows an Amazon page. For whatever reason, WebView.GoBack() sometimes does not do anything. Even the NavigationStarting or NavigationComplete events will get fired. Calling GoBack() a second time always works. As a workaround, I'm using a DispatcherTimer, which calls GoBack again, when NavigationStarting is not called shortly after the first GoBack call. Ugly workaround, but it works. I think there is definitely an issue in WebView.GoBack